# What does this declaration of array means in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, python-2.7

This is the declaration that confuses me: `dynamic=[0]*(10**5+5)`

What does it mean? I found it written [here](https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/21692429).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dynamic=[0]*(10**5+5)
```

This means a new list called 'dynamic' has been created with all its elements equal to 0. Size of list i.e. total number of elements in the list is equal to 10**5+5 which is equal to (10^5)+5 = 100005.